# Clear password field in other activity on exit

Tags: android

I need to  clear password field on exit of app,i am exiting the app in other activity and on exit it goes to mainActivity which has login details in which i need to clear password field,how will i do this in other activity ,i tried using setText("") but in vain.

```
public void backButtonHandler() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ReminderActivity.this);
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("Leave application?");
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave the application?");

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             //I need to clear here all pwd data present in MainActivity in edittext
                 finish();
                    }
                });
        // Setting Negative "NO" Button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `MainActivity` do like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    editText.SetText("");
}
```

So, it will clear `editText` value, whenever your `MainActivity` will get resumed.

Answer (score 1):

Or when you click the login button do

> editText.SetText("");

Then it will be cleared before another activity starts

Answer (score 0):

Using setText won't work and may even throw some type of NPE if your activity is no longer in memory.
There are a couple of ways you can do this depending on your requirements:

1. You can simply clear the text field in the activity/fragment's onStop or onDestroy overrides
2. If you absolutely have to set the text field from a different activity, then I suggest the following design:

In your Application class, create a nested class that implements ActivityLifeCycleCallbacks. This is a great class to implement as it allows you to monitor the state of all of your activities. It resolved a lot of problems for me
If you have a singleton model, or static String value that binds to your password TextView then you're almost there (other workarounds available if you give us more info).

So let's look at some code:

Design 1:

```
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
   myTextField.setText("");
}
```

Your Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  ...
  private static final class MyActivityLifeCycleCallback implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
{

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity)
    {
        //Here, I am assuming that your class name is MainActivity
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityStopped:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
        if("MainActivity".isEqual(activity.getLocalClassName())
        {
            myDataModel.getInstance().setPassword("");
            //or if your password String member is static
            //((MainActivity)activity).myPasswordMember = "";
        }


         //Or if you want to only clear the password text when RAActivity stops, simply replace "MainActivity" with the RAActivity class name.

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityDestroyed:" + activity.getLocalClassName());
        if(activity.getLocalClassName().contains("MySecondActivity"))
        {
//reset your password here - implementation will depend on how you have your data model organized (private, singleton, static, etc.)
        }

    }

   ....

  }
```

Remember that this design would work well with some type of a singleton or central data model (think MVC architecture) so that you can propagate the change in data to your components.

Hope it helps

EDIT:
I have added the code according to your comment. But to be honest, I think it's a better idea to simply call the setText("") method in the MainActivity's onStop function like I suggested. This is a simple problem and my second design might be a bit too much. Anyway, the code is updated, so if you like it, mark it as an answer :)

Here's another idea. IF RAActivity calls MainActivity again (probably not) using startActivity, you can simply pass a bundle value to MainActivity that tells it that it's coming from RAActivity. That way, MainActivity can clear the password if it was called from RAActivity. Lots of options.

Comment: I have like MainActivity which has login screen and RActivity from where i exit the application and go to MainActivity ,can you show me the steps considering this.I have added the exit function in my post.

Comment: Actually before your post itself i accepted it n then i got your post :)